# Custom Background - In SLRs

Tags: post-processing, photo-editing, digital, slr, background

There is a background image. We can take a new picture with some white/black background, and select the required parts from this new photo and put it in background image. This can be done using any photo editor, say Photoshop.

But my question is, is it possible to set the custom background in camera, so that we can adjust the zoom properly to match the background image. Something similar to PhotoBooth in Mac OS X.

Is it possible to do this in an SLRs?

Comment: I suppose it is possible that it's another, but it seems to me that you already asked this question about a year ago.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer : no, not possible.

More elaborate : by principle an SLR camera shows "reality" in the viewfinder through a mirror, so you can't do any "processing" on that.

However, nowadays there are hybrid cameras with electronic viewfinders (and still an interchangeable lens system) and liveview systems, so it might become possible.
But I'm not aware of any DSLR doing that in real time (yet ?!). To my knowledge it's only available on a webcam connected to a computer or a smartphone/tablet camera (because of the processing power required I suppose).